# In minecraft, my break and place buttons are broken. Why can't i fix it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, my break and place buttons are broken. When i try to place blocks it breaks them and places the block in my hand. How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the binding to make sure they are correct?

Answer (score 1):

You might have switched the buttons. Try going into the controls and change them. The new update allows you to define your own controls (such as Pick Block).